# No permission to write APN settings

Tags: android, android-studio

Saludos, estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android  para que cree una apn, el problema persiste en que me genera una excepción de tipo

```
Java.Lang.SecurityException
```

En mi manifiesto tengo como permiso un

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS"
```

El mensaje que me da la excepción es

> No permission to write APN settings

Pero como ya vieron ya tengo el permiso que necesita esa acción.

Esto lo necesito porque estoy desarrollando una aplicación que hará uso del `apn` para conectarse solamente.

Estoy trabando para Android 6(API 23) y he realizado las pruebas en 2 dispositivos diferentes. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tal vez tienes la misma experiencia que yo, trate de realizar una aplicación similar y el problema es que si trataba de usar el permiso : WRITE_APN_SETTINGS requería que la aplicación fuera definida como de sistema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso el permiso [**WRITE_APN_SETTINGS**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_APN_SETTINGS) que permite a las aplicaciones cambien la configuración de un APN (Access Point Name), **requiere estrictamente que tu aplicación sea configurada como aplicación de sistema.**

Es por esta razón que aunque tengas definido el permiso al ejecutar tu aplicación muestra el mensaje:

> No permission to write APN settings

Una aplicación de sistema tiene privilegios Root y están instaladas en la partición del sistema.

---

Me parecería que no es tu caso realizar una aplicación de sistema, pero agrego un [artículo](https://www.movilzona.es/tutoriales/android/root/como-convertir-una-aplicacion-de-android-en-una-aplicacion-del-sistema/) acerca de esto:

> Por defecto la ROM de Android cuenta con una serie de
> aplicaciones necesarias para el correcto funcionamiento del sistema
> operativo. Estas aplicaciones son las que conocemos como “aplicaciones
> básicas” que se instalan por defecto junto al propio sistema operativo
> y se clasifican como “aplicaciones del sistema”.
>
> Estas aplicaciones tienen ciertas preferencias sobre las aplicaciones
> de los usuarios, por ejemplo, que no pueden desinstalarse fácilmente y
> que para hacerlo se necesitan permisos de superusuario, o “root”.
> Aunque no es recomendable que las aplicaciones de usuario sean
> aplicaciones del sistema (entre otras cosas porque el espacio de la
> partición del sistema, o ROM, es bastante limitado), sí que es posible
> convertir algunas aplicaciones concretas en aplicaciones del sistema
> para asegurarnos que van a funcionar siempre y que ninguna persona no
> autorizada podrá eliminarlas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero la no tengo root en el dispositivo, y no puedo hacerlo por cuestiones de la empresa. Pero lo tomare en cuenta para futuros proyectos

Comment: Lo entiendo Emanuel de hecho yo desconocía este detalle cuando inicié un pequeño proyecto, al final lo suspedí, saludos.