# java.lang.SecurityException: setTime: Neither user 10168 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

Mi problema es el siguiente. Necesito configurar la hora y la fecha en el sistema desde mi aplicación, pero en el momento de intentar configurarla, envía ese error, luego probé con `AlarmManager`, pero también me envió el error, hasta intenté realizar la solicitud de permiso en ejecución según la documentación oficial. Pero nisiquiera muestra el diálogo, ¿de qué otra manera podría intentarlo?. Cabe destacar que no puede hacerse con un dispositivo rooteado, estoy probando en android `Lollipop`. Intenté esto:

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Fragment:

```
private Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.set(Year, Month, DayofMonth, finalhour, finalminutes);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

[Que encontré aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android). Pero de igual forma, me sigue enviando este error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: setTime: Neither user 10168 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME.

Entiendo el nivel de protección del permiso, ¿pero no hay otra forma de lograrlo?. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El permiso [SET_TIME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_TIME) solo puede ser utilizado para aplicaciones de sistema.

**NO disponible para aplicaciones de terceros.**

> Pero para poder asignar este permiso tu aplicación debe ser
>   configurada como aplicación de sistema, si tu aplicación no es de
>   sistema, aunque tengas configurados los permisos, estos no podrán ser
>   asignados.

---

Esta pregunta es relacionada a un permiso que solo puede ser usado en aplicaciones de sistema:

[No permission to write APN settings](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94945/no-permission-to-write-apn-settings/94972#94972)

Te sugiero leer estos artículo:

[CÓMO CONVERTIR UNA APLICACIÓN DE ANDROID EN UNA APLICACIÓN DEL SISTEMA](https://www.movilzona.es/tutoriales/android/root/como-convertir-una-aplicacion-de-android-en-una-aplicacion-del-sistema/)

[Convertir cualquier App a Aplicación de sistema en Android Root](http://movilandroide.blogspot.mx/2017/05/convertir-cualquier-app-aplicacion-de.html)