# no funciona .delete en tarjeta externa

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.
Tengo una app de reproducción de música, todo funciona bien solo me esta fallando la parte de  eliminar de archivos
tengo este método:

```
 private void Eliminar(String ubi){
        Log.d("setup", "Eliminar:   --"+ubi);
        try {
            if (reproducir.get(pos).isPlaying()) {
                reproducir.get(pos).pause();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){}
    if(ubi!=null) {
        Log.d( "Eliminar: ","Si existe");
        File eliminar=new File(ubi);

            myHand.removeCallbacks(CorreAnim);
            myHand.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            handlerAnim.removeCallbacks(UpdateSongTime);
            handlerAnim.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            reproducir.get(pos).stop();
            reproducir.get(pos).release();
            boolean result=eliminar.delete();
            Log.d("Delete", "Eliminar: "+eliminar);
            try {
                if (result){
                    for(int a=0;a<Original.size();a++){
                        Log.d("eliminar"+ubi, "lista: "+Original.get(a).getUri());
                        if(ubi.equals(Original.get(a).getUri())){
                            canciones.remove(a);
                            reproducir.remove(a);
                            Original.remove(a);
                            Log.d("Removido de listas", ": "+videoList.get(a).getUri());
                            if(ubi.equals(listaADP.get(a).getUri())){
                                listaADP.remove(a);
                                Canciones.adaptadorBiblioteca.notifyItemRemoved(a);
                                Log.d("Notifica", ":a Canciones ");
                            }
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    preferencias();
                    Next();
                    myHand.postDelayed(CorreAnim, 200);
                    Toast.makeText(Reproduciendo.getInstance(), " La canción:  " + eliminar.getName() + " Se elimino correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Log.d( "Eliminar: ","result "+result);
                    Next();
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d( "Eliminar: ",":"+e);
            }

        } else {
            Log.d("Eliminar: ", "   no es un archivo valido :  " + ubi);
            Toast.makeText(Reproduciendo.getInstance(), " No es un archivo valido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            reproducir.get(pos).start();
            myHand.postDelayed(CorreAnim, 200);
        }

    }
```

funciona bien para eliminar archivos con ruta /Storege/emulate/0/...
pero no con archivos en la sd que tienen una ruta /Storage/A515-1690/...

tengo declarado en mi manifest los permisos WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE y READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tambien tengo la solicitud en tiempo de ejecución asi:

```
private void VerificaPermisos(){
        int PermisoLeer =ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int PermisoEscribir=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi") int PermisoForegraund=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE);
        if(PermisoLeer== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        if(PermisoEscribir==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        if(PermisoForegraund==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE},REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por fin lo pude solucionar
lo que implemente fue justamente Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
Les dejo el código por si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema.

Primero lanzo el intent desde un alertDialog

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(Reproduciendo.getInstance()).setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>!!ALERTA¡¡")).setMessage(" ¿Desea eliminar la cancion: " + f.getName() + "?")
                    .setPositiveButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>Si"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                            intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, getFilesDir());
                            startActivityForResult(intent,200);
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>No"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Toast.makeText(Reproduciendo.getInstance(), "No se elimino la Cancion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).show();
```

Esto nos muestra el sistema de archivos, tenemos que seleccionar la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo a borrar. Y en ActivityonResult asigno permisos y elimino desde contentUri

```
    @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String treeUri = null;
                if (data != null){
//treeUri es un string 
                    treeUri = data.getDataString();
                }
                Log.d("Regresa", "onActivityResult: "+treeUri);
                if (treeUri != null ) {
//se convierte en uri
                    UriSD= Uri.parse(treeUri);
                    Log.d("ResultFinal: "," --"+treeUri+"--"+UriSD);
                    content=getContentResolver();
//Se asignan los permisos al uri
              content.takePersistableUriPermission(UriSD,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    try {
                        if (reproducir.get(pos).isPlaying()) {
                            reproducir.get(pos).pause();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){}
                    if(Elim!=null) {
                        Log.d( "Eliminar: ","Si existe");
                        File provider=new File(Elim);
//Se crea un documentFile con el uri al que le dimos permisos y listamos los archivos
                        DocumentFile doc=DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getApplicationContext(),UriSD);
                        DocumentFile[] index=doc.listFiles();
                        Uri uri=null;
                        DocumentFile delete=null;
                        for(int a=0;a<index.length;a++){
//Buscamos nuestro archivo a borrar
                            if(provider.getName().equals(index[a].getName())) {
    
                                Log.d("DocumetFile", "Nombre: "+index[a].getName()+":Uri-"+index[a].getUri()+"-Permiso-"+index[a].canWrite());
  //Creamos un documentFail con el uri correspondiente 
                         delete=DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(getApplicationContext(), index[a].getUri());
                            }
                        }
                        myHand.removeCallbacks(CorreAnim);
                        myHand.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        handlerAnim.removeCallbacks(UpdateSongTime);
                        handlerAnim.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        reproducir.get(pos).stop();
                        reproducir.get(pos).release();
//y aqui procedemos al delete
                        boolean result=delete.delete();
                        Log.d("Delete", "Eliminar: "+result+"--"+provider);
                            try {
                            if (result){
                                for(int a=0;a<Original.size();a++){
                                    Log.d("eliminar"+Elim, "lista: "+Original.get(a).getUri());
                                    if(Elim.equals(Original.get(a).getUri())){
                                        canciones.remove(a);
                                        reproducir.remove(a);
                                        Original.remove(a);
                                        Log.d("Removido de listas", ": "+videoList.get(a).getUri());
                                        if(Elim.equals(listaADP.get(a).getUri())){
                                            listaADP.remove(a);
                                            Canciones.adaptadorBiblioteca.notifyItemRemoved(a);
                                            Log.d("Notifica", ":a Canciones ");
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
    
                                }
                                preferencias();
                                Next();
                                myHand.postDelayed(CorreAnim, 200);
                                Toast.makeText(Reproduciendo.getInstance(), " La canción:  " + provider.getName() + " Se elimino correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Log.d( "Eliminar: ","result "+result);
                                Next();
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Log.d( "Result: ","Ex -"+e);
                        }
    
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Eliminar: ", "   no es un archivo valido :  " + Elim);
                        Toast.makeText(Reproduciendo.getInstance(), " No es un archivo valido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        reproducir.get(pos).start();
                        myHand.postDelayed(CorreAnim, 200);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d("result ","uri is empty!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Esto funciono para mi, espero le sirva a alguien mas

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente, **no es suficiente declarar el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, la petición de este permiso debe declararse también manualmente**, te sugiero revisar:

[Obtener permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24934/95)

Al requerir el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, no es necesario definir o requerir el permiso `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

---

De acuerdo a lo que comentas, tratas de escribir/leer fuera de la estructura de archivos que genera tu app, actualmente por cuestiones de seguridad esto no es posible ya.

> funciona bien para eliminar archivos con ruta /Storege/emulate/0/...
> pero no con archivos en la sd que tienen una ruta /Storage/A515-1690/

ahora debes usar `getExternalFilesDir()` de esta forma:

```
File carpeta = new File( getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/Folder");
```

pero en este caso se creará el directorio dentro de la estructura de archivos de la aplicación:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/Folder
```

solo aquí puedes escribir y crear un directorio, este es un cambio que realizó Google principalmente por seguridad.

Comment: Si lo tengo contemplado, ya edité la pregunta y agregó el método mediante el cual solicito los permisos

Comment: ya veo, cual es el problema, actualizó la respuesta!

Comment: Ok ya lo revise y getExternalFilesDir() regresa esto: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.reproducthor/files

Por lo que no me sirven ahí no se encuentran mis archivos.
Entiendo las restricciones, pero imagino que debe existir alguna forma de realizarlo ya que desde otros reproductores como pi reproductor si me permite eliminar archivos en la sd

Comment: Lo que sucede es que esas apps tienen permisos especiales o son apps de sistema, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/244849/95

Comment: No creo que ese sea el problema, ya investigando logre entender que se debe hacer una solicitud para asignar los permisos a un arbol de directorios por medio de:
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE); y lanzándola con un startActivityforResult() lo que no logro entender es como recibir o almacenar este resultado